# How does law of reflection work at the atomic level?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, reflection

I read that

when light strikes an object some of the frequencies of light are absorbed while others are reflected back  this is explained in more detail by physics classroom:

Visible Light Reflection and Transmission
Reflection  light waves occur because the frequencies of the light waves do not match the natural frequencies of vibration of the objects. When light waves of these frequencies strike an object, the electrons in the atoms of the object begin vibrating. But instead of vibrating in resonance at a large amplitude, the electrons vibrate for brief periods of time with small amplitudes of vibration; then the energy is reemitted as a light wave.

My question is why is does'nt the atom re-emit the light wave in the direction it came ? why does it reemit ensuring ( angle of i=angle of  r)

Source = https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/Light-Absorption,-Reflection,-and-Transmission

Comment: Check this answer: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-metals-reflect-more-light

Comment: Reflection cannot be fully described on the level of a single-atom response. It is a collective effect and related to the bulk behavior of the charge carriers on the boundary.